# How to set starting options in facebook messenger for pages?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-page, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to set **starting options** in **facebook messenger for pages** like example bellow:
[example of expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOQuc.jpg)

I figured that similar could be achieved by using messenger BOT with 'start button', multiple BOT replies with 'quick reply' buttons and passing conversation to live chat in required cases.

The problem with this is that after user clicks 'get started' button BOT publish text replay 'Get started' which is not desired.

**I wonder if there is an build-in setting to achieve this? If not, how would one solve it?**

*EDIT: It seems to me, it is not possible to build something like that neither with facebook quick reply neither with templates/buttons*

*EDIT 2: I also tried doing this in Facebook's page settings with no result. It seems it doesn't have anything to do with Facebook's 'quick replies'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no way to set those options from facebook platform itself. Those questions are generated by facebook to give user a head start to a conversation and those are generated based on the type of page you are created. To see the option go to

Your Page's Settings-> Messaging -> General Settings

[image]

It is ideal that you will configure the 'Get Started' to initiate conversation with your bot and then show users a bunch of options using various templates like quick replies, carousel, list etc. By this way you have full control over your templates and expected answers.

But then again if you want to use those generated options from facebook then you can look for those option's text in the delivered json to your configured web hook. Here is a sample json:

{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"","time":1519980744192,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":""},"recipient":{"id":""},"timestamp":1519980743903,"message":{"mid":"","seq":1,"text":"Could you give me a call? I'd like to speak to someone."}}]}]}

Look at the 'text' attribute. The text is from after clicking one of those options. But again this is not ideal as the options can get changed anytime by facebook's algorithm.

My suggestion is to use 'Get Started' button and then send a list to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately I don't see this option in Page Settings. I even tried changing Page type to all possible templates, with no change.

I figured similar result can be achieved using a BOT, it just looks a bit different - like an 'actual' conversation - meaning: it seems BOT always need to respond with a text, not just with buttons. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have just created a page with Branding->Clothing page type and the option appeared. And what do you mean by "always need to respond with a text"... after a button click or quick reply button click the text of the button is shown in the messenger UI as a clue to the user so that he can see what option he selected. But in webhook facebook will always deliver correct type of json with postbacks for each template (button, list, quick replies etc) so that you can respond accordingly. I suggest you to look : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Comment: Well, we have 2 pages and this appeared on one of them by itself, but other still doesn't have this option. They both have business template. Anyway I am counting this question solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you posted shows a features that is currently being tested for Pages, so it is not available to every Page. There is no built-in way to do this, other than sending quick replies in response to the get started postback, messaging_optins or messaging_referrals events.

Comment: "_The screenshot you posted shows a features that is currently being tested for Pages, so it is not available to every Page._" -- I was afraid it's something like that. Did you perhaps found some documentation/blog post/etc about this being tested?

Comment: @Pavle Topic has been brought up several times on the Messenger Platform dev group

Answer (score 0):

You can create a persistent menu to achieve this.
Here are few video tutorials I created to help you with Facebook integration and sending rich messages in facebook messenger through Dialogflow.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ4HoYxoKl8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC9Y-AmcL6A